# CentOS-7 disk name change on reboot in hyperv

Tags: hyper-v, centos7, mount

On hyper-V, one IDE and 7 SCSI hdd are attached. IDE disk is configured in LVM and scsi hdd is configured in standard partition. During reboot the disk name get shuffle. There is no error message.

From the dmesg, I see that this get shuffled.

Due to this need to application failed to start and remount again looking partition size.

Kindly assist.

[/dev/sdf change to /dev/sdh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAKko.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is known behavior for a linux system. The sequence that block devices are added in at boot time is arbitrary, so you certainly could see issues with devices moving around unless you use some sort of persistent naming scheme such as disk labels or UUID.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming for more details and a basic tutorial.

Comment: Above solution worked fine.
Pasting Redhat link for same.
url :- 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/persistent_naming.html